# Is a crack in my home's floor slab a concern?

Tags: concrete, basement

Hose outlet pipe burst because we failed to winterize. This is our first floor/ground floor.Tore out carpeting to dry. Found this big crack in our concrete slab. Question: is this an issue? And if so, what should I do?[image]

Answer (score 5):

Slab cracks like this are common and usually not a problem. If there is rebar or steel mesh in the slab it will usually just crack over time but the rebar or mesh provides the strength to stay in place. If the slab starts settling or shifting then there is a problem and the cause needs to be identified like a leaking pipe or drain taking the soil away that would need to be fixed first then the slab repaired. If it was an original failure to prepare the site grout can be pumped through the slab to correct any settling but your crack looks normal and like it has not shifted so I would not worry about it.

Comment: Yep. All slabs crack. It's just a matter of how well they're controlled.

Comment: If you have a radon mitigation system installed, you should caulk the crack so you don't lose air that you've spent energy heating/cooling to the vacuum. Otherwise you don't really need to do anything unless you notice the crack getting much worse over time.